# What do you mean by "disabled on upgrade to [xenial]"

Tags: apt, upgrade, lubuntu

In a now upgraded Lubuntu 16.04 LTS, I checked **Software and Upgrades** and clicked the **Other Software Tab**. Here I should see some PPAs and stuff for my stuff can upgrade.

A lot of them say **Disabled on Upgrade to *Xenial***, Xenial being what I think 16.04 is.

I also noticed that whenever I **`sudo apt-get update`** the list is obviously shorter.

I feel something needs to be done that involves **re-installing** about 5 GB worth of software, but I need to know what this officialy means first.

So, what does it mean when it said **Disabled on Upgrade**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During an upgrade of one release to another (say 14.04 to 16.04, or 16.10 to 17.04), only the official repositories are meant to be used. All other repositories (including PPAs) are disabled by the upgrade tool. While disabling them, the tool leaves a comment noting this: "Disabled on Upgrade to ...".

Comment: So, as a comment, it doesn't mean anything? I could just re-enable them, and remove the comment?

Comment: @dgood1 Other than being a note to the user, it has no special significance. You can remove it or edit as you please. Of course, before re-enabling them, you should check that the repos do support 16.04/xenial (or whichever version you're on now).

Comment: Many thanks. Might be a good idea to put that note in the answer.

Comment: how can you enable them back?